# WCF Proxy - SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

Is it possible to configure a WCF proxy such that it is able to understand SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 messages at the same time? In other words, I want to be able to connect to a web service that may return at any time, SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 based messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to have two different WCF End Points for the two different SOAP versions. You would also have to know which version of SOAP response is going to be returned ahead of time by the call.

There's no way in WCF to make a single end-point flip between the two versions automatically.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I was hoping there was something I'm missing. I think I can solve my problem another way, but that's the exact issue. I can't know which version of message I'm going to get back.